# Echo / Output 0 (zero) is not working

Tags: php, echo

I'm running a query to get the total sum of some hours from a database table to show in a PDF file but for some strange reason it won't echo 0 (zero).

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, SUM(hours_night), SUM(hours_days) FROM table WHERE invoiceID='".mysql_real_escape_string($invoiceID)."'") or die(mysql_error());
 $result = mysql_num_rows($query);

 $totalhours_night = 0;


     while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

         $totalhours_night += $fetch['SUM(hours_night)'];
     }


$html_output = "Some html and tables markup... " . $totalhours_night . "";
```

The output of the html works fine, thats not the problem.. but the problem is it won't output 0 (zero) for some reason. If the hour result is actualy something like 1 or 5 or whatever it outputs the totalhours fine, but i need it to output 0 if there are no hours.

Because it looks strange to ouput nothing if there are no hours, i need to display a 0 zero since this looks more good.

BTW, if i for example put number_format($totalhours_night, 2); it does display 0.00, but i need it to be just 0.

Comment: What is with number_format and the second parameter 0

Comment: How do you output 0? With `echo $totalhours_night;`? If so PHP will indeed output nothing in that case (which I've always found very annoying). Just do `echo $totalhours_night . '';` instead.

Comment: @Laurent [Wat?](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) `echo 0;` → `0`.

Comment: @Adriaan That's quite some complicated logic. `if ($fetch['SUM(hours_night)'] != 0)` is `false`, then `$fetch['SUM(hours_night)']` is `0`, in which case `$totalhours_night = $fetch['SUM(hours_night)'];` will do just fine. Also, no need for a `while` loop to fetch the results, since you only have *one* result.

Comment: Do some debugging by `var_dump()`ing a bunch of variables here and there to see what their value is and which `if..else` actually gets executed.

Comment: @Laurent I don't realy use echo, i need it to display 0 if the SUM(hours_night) is 0. I save the content in $html_output and later i use this to display this in a PDF.

Comment: how do you output it when you generate the PDF?

Comment: @NiftyDude, thats not the problem, the output to PDF is working fine. The only thing that won't work is to actualy output a simple 0.

If for example the total nighthours are 5, the 5 displays without any problems. Ive also tried doing this $totalhours_night = '0'; but this also won't work.

Comment: @Adriaan I was asking because it might have something to do with outputting to pdf, but if you do `echo $totalhours_night` when it's '0', does it output fine in your browser?

Comment: @NiftyDude, yes it does just echo's 0.

Comment: hm ok... Then it's *probably* something to do maybe with the library you are using to output pdf.. Good luck and wait for better answer :)

Comment: @deceze, right sorry it's `echo null;` that doesn't print anything.

Comment: @NiftyDude, i doubt that. If i use for example number_format() it displays 0.00, which is also good for a solution but i dont like to see my hours like 0.00 and 5.00 i just need 0 or 5 or 5.25, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Treat integer as string like this-

```
echo (string)$totalhours_night;
```

Comment: you deleted your answer, then repost the exact same just to avoid the downvote?

Comment: What? There was no link for editing it. Im on mobile safari. What do u want me to do? You mean it's still there even though it's deleted?

Comment: That's (un)useful. ;) Do you have rep enough to remove posts as well? There really was no editing link in mobile safari. Is the editing link removed after a downvote or what?

Comment: No it shouldn't disappear just like that. In any case, I don't think this has nothing to do with OP's problem (I deleted my answer as well after realising my answer didn't really help him) :), and for your record, I didn't downvote you

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. Your SQL query is wrong, you can't display `id` and `SUM(..)` unless you use `GROUP BY id` (Which kid of loses the idea if `id` is unique)
2. If you use `SUM(..)` give it an alias like `SUM(..) AS alias1`, and later in the PHP refer to `alias1`.
3. If this is not the reason, try `var_dump($fetch['alias1']);` and look at what you really get back. (And post your findings here so we can give you further help)

Comment: 1. So if i lose the id, the query is good, since i use WHERE invoiceID='blabla'.

Thanks for your insight ;)

Comment: Well there is a fundamental difference between `WHERE` and `GROUP BY`. `WHERE` is a filter, while rows that don't match don't appear. While `GROUP BY` just 'collapses' them together. Try searching for them to get the difference.